# EF MVC connection string and associations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have an application, if i take the connection string from the web-config everything work good, if i set the connection string when i create an new Context like this:

```
MyContext context = new MyContext("myconnectionString");
```

when i execute query and i try to pass from an entity to another return me that is null like this

```
MyContext context = new MyContext("myconnectionString");

var qLegals = from x in context.ContactsLegals
                        where x.end == null
                        orderby x.start descending
                        select x;

qLegals.First().ContactsLegalDetails.First();
```

ContactsLegalDetails is null, is like have lost all the associations
i try to change

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled
```

but it still not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions :

- use Eager loading ( using .Include() - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#eager )
- use Lazy loading - the property "ContactsLegalDetails" should be virtual - thats enabling Lazy loading, so until you wont try to access ContactsLegalDetails you wont have it .

**Edit :**

There is no use to touch :

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled
```

by default it will be enabled, you can use this property to disable LazyLoading to serialize objects for e.g .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a partial class for your context class, which will going to take connection string as parameter in constructor like this :

```
public partial class YourContextClass: DbContext
{
    public YourContextClass(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) 
    {
          Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString; 
    }
}
```

And after this if you create object with connectionstring as parameter then this will work i.e.

```
YourContextClass context = new YourContextClass ("myconnectionString");
```

Thanks

Comment: My problem isn't the connection to database, this work well, my problem is that don't load relationships between tables.

Comment: Now adding Include <> to a query adding all the tables that i need it work... but i wouldn't add Include to all my query. There's a solution?